# What's 'glBufferData' for in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es

I run across a sample OpenGL code that I ported to OpenGL ES 2.0 (there wasn't much to be done actually), but I cannot help wondering what the `glBufferData` function is for. The original source is like that:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2 * 6, quad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, (void *) 0);
```

But I can successfully simplify it as:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, quad);
```

That is, I can omit the `glBufferData` function just by using a valid pointer to the quad array in `glVertexAttribPointer`.

So, could anyone explain what's the `glBufferData` function for? From what I'm doing it seems to be redundant but that must be because of my serious lack of knowledge of the API. As a matter of fact I tried reading the docs at [khronos.org](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) but this didn't help me understand its use.

Comment: In addition to what's been said in the answers, I believe the name of the concept you're looking for here is a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO): http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are reusing the same data in multiple frames, using `glBufferData` as part of your setup/initialization will transfer data from the CPU to the GPU only once.  Whereas `glVertexAttribPointer` must be called every frame, so using it to transfer data results in using a lot more bus bandwidth.

If you're updating the attribute array every frame, there's not much advantage one way or the other.

Comment: Aha! I'm working on something like a image processing API so the vertices won't change (not to mention that there are only six of them). Thanks a lot! Highly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is not the call to glVertexAttribPointer (in fact you call it with offset 0 nevertheless). The key idea is, that using glBufferData one creates a working copy of the data in "fast memory" (i.e. the RAM a GPU has direct access to), instead of having to transfer the vertices attributes between memory domains (i.e. CPU → GPU) every time glDrawElements or glDrawArrays is called. It also means that you can free the memory with the data in your program after copying to "fast" memory.

Comment: `glBufferData` is only really useful if you're instancing geometry right? If you wanted to draw a model 50 times in different places you call `glBufferData` once, then do your transforms and `glDrawArrays` etc. But if you had 50 *different* models to draw, you have to call `glBufferData` for each model, or just skip it and pass the vertex data into `glVertexAttribPointer`? Or alternatively you could concat *all* your vertex data into one array, call `glBufferData` on that array and then pass in separate offsets to `glVertexAttribPointer`, I imagine that is the fastest way?

Comment: @Soup: VBO helps when you draw multiple times from the same data.  Could be instances, but could also be subsequent frames.  And yes, concatenating multiple models into one VBO is recommended, since binding new VBOs is more costly than changing the offset.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm working on an OpenGL 2.0 program to display multiple instances/copies of the same object do you know of any tutorials/examples, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is weird. If leaving out glBufferData works the same, then either no buffer is bound, or there is a glBufferData call earlier in the program. I was confused whether maybe OpenGL ES had some significantly different "special behaviour", but I've checked the specs, and from what I can see, it works exactly the same as in "normal" OpenGL.

Drawing (via glDraw[Elements|Arrays]) will read from the pointer previously supplied by glVertexAttribPointer if **no** buffer is bound (client memory). It will read from the buffer if one is bound, treating the glVertexAttribPointer pointer argument as an offset into the buffer. Drawing from a buffer that has not been initialized is obviously not defined.

What does glBufferData do?

glBufferData does at least two things, and optionally a third. It allocates buffer storage and lays down the usage of the buffer. Optionally, if the pointer argument is non-null, it will fill the buffer with the pointed-to data. The similar glBufferSubData differs insofar as it only updates (possibly a subrange of) data, it does not allocate storage or anything else.