# glVertexAttribPointer in OpenGL and in OpenGLES

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es

I'm reading tutorials about OpenGL and OpenGLES and I'm a bit confused about the use of the function `glVertexAttribPointer` in these two APIs.

In the **OpenGL** tutorial this function uses as last parameter a numeric offset (with a casting to  const GLVoid*) and I suppose that the vertices are directly taken from the current Array Buffer.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(vs_position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (const GLvoid*) (3*sizeof(GLfloat)) );
```

In the **OpenGLES** tutorial the last parameter points directly to a structure which represents vertices:

```
GLFloat vertices[] = {...definition};
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
```

I can't understand how these 2 functions work. Are they totally different functions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are the same function being used in two different ways. I'd explain why it works this way, but you won't care, and it's for very stupid and irrelevant reasons.

What matters is what they're doing. And what they're doing depends on something that you didn't show: *what is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.*

See, the behavior of `glVertexAttribPointer` *changes* depending on that. If there is no buffer object bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when you call `glVertexAttribPointer`, then the function will assume that the final value is a *pointer* (like the function's name says: glVertexAttrib**Pointer**). Specifically, it is a pointer into client-owned memory.

When it comes time to render, the vertex attribute data will come from the previously provided pointer. Thus, the second example is just using an array of client data, declared in standard C style, as the source data. No buffer objects are involved.

Note: the core profile of OpenGL 3.1+ removed the ability to use client memory; there, you *must* use buffer objects, as explained below.

If a buffer object is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` when `glVertexAttribPointer` is called, then something special happens. OpenGL will pretend that the pointer (which is what the final parameter is as far as C/C++ is concerned) is actually a *byte offset* into the buffer bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. It will convert the pointer into an integer and then store that integer offset and the buffer object currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

So the above code takes `3*sizeof(GLfloat)`, the byte offset, and converts it into a pointer. OpenGL will take the pointer and convert it back into an offset, yielding `3*sizeof(GLfloat)` again.

When it comes time to render, OpenGL will then read from the previously given buffer object, using the previously given offset.

The first example puts the vertex data into a buffer object in GPU memory. The second example puts the vertex data in a regular C/C++ array, in CPU memory.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you. 
- Where did you get this information?! I can't find documentation about that.
- what you say about OpenGL3.1 and not using memory client is valid for OpenGLEs 2.0 too?

Comment: @MatterGoal: Generally speaking, applications either always use client-side memory or buffer objects. So nobody needs to talk about the difference between them. And much of the desktop OpenGL documentation has shifted to the core profile behavior, so it doesn't talk about it either. But it's right there in the [man pages for GL ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml). Just read the second paragraph of the description.

Comment: @MatterGoal: It's also explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5402762/734069) in a related question.

Comment: Good explanation.  I think I passed `&offset`, where `int offset=(3*sizeof(GLfloat))` several times before figuring out that yeah, your plain ol' integer is to be passed to OpenGL _cast as a pointer to memory address 12.._.  I can't exactly chalk this bad API to "a consequence of being a C API with no support for overloads.." this appears to me to be just bad design and should really be 2 separate functions.

Comment: @bobobobo: Oh, it has nothing to do with being a C API. It has to do with backwards compatibility. When ARB_VBO came out, they wanted to make it so that users could very easily adapt their code to it. So all you have to do is change your pointers to offsets and issue a bind call before setting up your pointers. Of course, 10+ years later, it makes the API look powerfully stupid. But the ARB seems to enjoy making short-sighted API decisions; this is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

[GL spec](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) clearly mentions this:

case 1:  If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target while a generic vertex attribute array is specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.

case 2: Specifies a pointer to the first component of the first generic vertex attribute in the array.